# For looping a list in Android for a list of permissions

Tags: android, loops, append

I am looping through a list and trying to append a list of applications to a String but so far i am only able to append 1 application only. It works fine if i try to add into an array and display it in a listview.

```
for (PackageInfo pi : apps) {
    String[] permissions = pi.requestedPermissions;
    String internetpermissionsText = "";
    if (permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            Log.d("TAG", permission);
                        if (permission.equals("android.permission.INTERNET")) {

                            String appname=pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();


                            internetpermissionsText += appname + "\n";

                            Log.e("TAG", "Im in!");

                            }

                            internetPermission.setText(internetpermissionsText);


                        }
```

The list of applications should display like

```
Angry Birds
Facebook
Twitter
Internet
```

but instead it just displays

```
Angry Birds
```

Logcat (Too much spam)
http://pastebin.com/PEs8z0Kf

Comment: You should post your actual loop. Since you get only one output, the error might be in the loop, that is missing in your above code.

Comment: Include both the manifest and logcat.

Comment: Like i said when i display it in an listview there isn't any problem displaying the list of applications as i just store it into an arraylist and display with listview and there is no logcat error so i can't show you any

Comment: Add some logging where you log each time you find an application that uses the internet permission and log the size of the array given to your ListView. It must be possible to find some clues by adding more logging ..

Comment: try moving the `internetpermissionsText` outside of the main `for (PackageInfo pi : apps) {` loop? and also, put `internetPermission.setText(internetpermissionsText);` at the outer body of the loop as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way, as I stated in the comment above:

```
String internetpermissionsText = "";
for (PackageInfo pi : apps) {
    String[] permissions = pi.requestedPermissions;
    if (permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            Log.d("TAG", permission);
            if (permission.equals("android.permission.INTERNET")) {
                String appname=pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
                internetpermissionsText += appname + "\n";
                Log.e("TAG", "Im in!");

            }
        }
    }
}
internetPermission.setText(internetpermissionsText);
```

Comment: I get a NullPointerException if i do that

Comment: internetPermission.setText(internetpermissionsText); this line

Comment: Do you have `internetPermission` variable set via `findViewById`. Its definitely not `internetpermissionsText` as that string is declared in my proposed answer.This is **your** code, you should be doing all this trying out things for yourself, debugging it etc.

Comment: Okay nevermind it works now i forget to set it to findViewById after reverting back so many times.